# Pandas DataFrame class like column naming

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is a way to define pandas DataFrame similarly to python class so that I can perform refactorings or other similar IDE operations more easily.

E.g. I have a DataFrame like below which I save to csv file:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'count': [10, 20, 30], 'products': ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon']})
>>> df.to_csv('products.csv')
```

Then I read this csv in another file and can directly access columns

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('products.csv')
>>> df.products
0     apple
1    banana
2     lemon
```

Now I would like to rename that column to something else in PyCharm in such a way that all usages would also be renamed.

Is there a way to wrap those DataFrames in some class (or something else) so that I can define columns and easily refactor them?

My idea was to define this DataFrame as class that would inherit from pandas DataFrame with implicitly defined fields:

```
class ProductsDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.products
        self.count
```

and then initialize it by:

```
df: ProductsDataFrame = ProductsDataFrame({'count': [10, 20, 30], 'products': ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon']})
```

but that still doesn't help PyCharm understand that `df.products` in one file is the same field as `df.products` in another and doesn't correctly rename when using `shift+f6`

Comment: What do you mean by 'refactor'?  Do you want to rename the columns in the file? Or rename the columns after you read the data back in?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can rename a variable like this: mark the variable -> right click -> refactor -> rename. or shift+f6

Comment: @James I would like to define the columns like you would define class fields so that I can easily refactor them in multiple files (I know that I would need to generate csv again but that's not a problem)

Comment: @luigigi that doesn't work for DataFrame columns

Comment: your question isnt really clear. do you want to change the column names? obviously you have to do that in your code and not by an IDE function

Comment: @luigigi I have added some additional explanation to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after playing around with it for some time I settled for:

```
class ProductsDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.products = self.products
        self.count = self.count
```

and then initialize it by:

```
df: ProductsDataFrame = ProductsDataFrame({'count': [10, 20, 30], 'products': ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon']})
```

with that if I have multiple occurrences of that class in multiple places I can easily refactor them as I would refactor other classes in PyCharm keeping all DataFrame capabilities.